# HTML 5 / CSS button beside dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a submit button beside my select option drop down menu. I can't seem to get to align properly above the message box.

It sits in a basic div but didn't think it was needed.

```
<form id="contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h5>Join us now</h5>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subject">
                                    Select Option</label>
                                <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                    <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                    <option value="service">Nutritional Support</option>
                                    <option value="suggestions">Nutritional Support and Exercise Pescription</option>
                                    <option value="product">Single Nutrition or Exercise Plan</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <label for="name">
                                Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                            Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: please provide the css you currently have

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: added fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/75jrohkm/ could you please specify your css and requirement ?

Comment: tried to upload the CSS but doesn't seem to save or look right as I'm using bootstrap I assume?

Comment: @NewUser is this something how it looks?http://jsfiddle.net/0t947zjb/. where should the submit button be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the rows and columns in your code, you can find it in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmuz6hnd/1/) , hope this helps.

```
<form id="contact-form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <h5>Join us now</h5>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="subject">
                        Select Option
                    </label>

                    <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                        <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                        <option value="service">Nutritional Support</option>
                        <option value="suggestions">Nutritional Support and Exercise Pescription</option>
                        <option value="product">Single Nutrition or Exercise Plan</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right buttonTest" id="btnContactUs">
                        Send Message
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">
                        Name
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">
                        Email Address
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                        </span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">
                        Message
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                              placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```